# AndroidSurfaceView Touch not working properly 

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm creating a chess Game, I am using flag variable to check white or black turn.

First i am creating a chess board by using surface view and drawing bitmap on that canvas to show element of chess.

But my problem is that when I touch canvas every time it call `onDraw()`-method even i am not calling `invalidate()`, and returning false in `onTouch()`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(white){
        // Code for select
        // Code for move element
        // IF Invalid move ( Donot want to call onDraw() so i return here   -
        false and i did not call invalidate() but it redraw view)
    }else if(black){
        // same code for balck
    }
}
```

Comment: and this is a problem because?

Comment: What njzk2 said. And, what is the question?

Comment: Problem is that onDraw() creating when i touch canvas either i am calling invalidate() or not

Comment: Do you have any other view also in the same layout, and are you doing any changing to them?. In case of any layout changes also onDraw will be called. As it is you can force to call the onDraw but not stopping of calling. Calling onDraw shouldn't change the state of the view, rather that should draw your state of the view. You should keep separate your state in member variables, and change according to the user action.

Comment: No i have single canvas on complete screen ,but when i touch it anywhere it redraw complete view again

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you always(?) return `false` by default. In general, if you have no idea what to return (returning `true` means you consumed that touch event), use `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` instead. However, this might not be relevant to your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply but my doubt is why canvas redraw complete view when i touch on canvas, although im not calling invalidate()